# Why the function append in Go work with reference when pass a slice?

Tags: go

In the next code I'm trying to add an element of a slice of slices, but as Go works with reference, how can I use this by using the b slice by value?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := []int{1}
    arr := [][]int{a}

    b := []int{2}

    arr = append(arr, b)
    fmt.Println(arr)

    b[0] = 3
    arr = append(arr, b)   

    fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

I expected that the last Println was [[1] [2] [3]], but it's [[1] [3] [3]].

Comment: You are using `b` by value, because everything in Go is passed by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to insert a slice "by value"; you need to make a [copy](https://godoc.org/builtin#copy) of the slice before inserting it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func copy_ints(c []int) []int {
    s := make([]int, len(c))
    copy(s, c)
    return s
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1}
    arr := [][]int{copy_ints(a)}

    b := []int{2}

    arr = append(arr, copy_ints(b))
    fmt.Println(arr)

    b[0] = 3
    arr = append(arr, copy_ints(b))

    fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Tds5FGj3nf